# Angular 4: Access Form Controls in HTML page

Tags: html, angular, angular4-forms

I am validating my HTML form in Angular 4 , wanted to enable/disable a button by checking if a form is valid/invalid

```
<form novalidate #shiftForm="ngForm">
   <table>
   <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>time</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody *ngFor=let item of Items>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="shiftName"
               [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftName"#shiftName="ngModel" id="shiftName">
               <div *ngIf="shiftName.invalid && (shiftName.dirty || shiftName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="shiftName.errors.required">REQUIRED</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="shiftTime"
               [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftTime" #shiftTime="ngModel" id="shiftTime">
               <div *ngIf="ShiftTime.invalid && (ShiftTime.dirty || ShiftTime.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="ShiftTime.errors.required">REQUIRED</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
<button [disabled]="shiftForm.invalid"
(click)="updateItems()">APPLY
</button>
</form>
```

component file :

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {Transition, StateService} from '@uirouter/angular';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'shift-details',
    templateUrl: './shift-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shift-details.component.less'],    
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ShiftDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    //variable declaration
    Items:any = [];

    constructor(
                private rd: Renderer2,                                        
                private transition: Transition,
                private $state: StateService) {
        this.$stateParams = transition.params();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.Items = getShiftItems();      
    }

    getShiftItems() {
    //calling the service here to load the data in this.Items     

    }


    updateItems() {
     //calling the service here to update this.Items

     }

}
```

Even though when both the input fields are empty and showing the validation error `shiftForm.invalid` is still not disabling the button. I have tried `shiftForm.form.shiftName.invalid`, `shiftform.shiftName.invalid`, `shiftForm.form['shiftName'].invalid`,`shiftForm.controls['shiftName'].invalid` etc.. None of them are working. Even when i try just the element name directly like `shiftName.invalid` or `shiftName.errors` still the button is not getting disabled.

What am i doing wrong ? I wanted to validate the form in HTML file only, do not want to do reactive form validation in the typescript file.

Comment: can you add your component.ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `name` property of each of the controls. `name` property needs to be unique.

So change...

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required name="shiftName"
       [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftName"#shiftName="ngModel" id="shiftName">
```

to

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required 
       name="shiftName-{{item.ShiftName}}"
       [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftName" #shiftName="ngModel" id="shiftName">
```

and do the same change for `shiftTime` control too.

Also, you have a typo in the `*ngIf` checks for `shiftTime`. It should be `shiftTime` and not `ShiftTime`.

Please check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txiaed)

Comment: Please add relevant code from stackblitz to the answer here.

Comment: Thanks @sabithpocker

Comment: @Srini did you check the demo on stackblitz? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i did check it just now. Its working. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Try this set of code. it will work

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {Transition, StateService} from '@uirouter/angular';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'shift-details',
    templateUrl: './shift-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shift-details.component.less'],    
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ShiftDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    //variable declaration
    Items:any = [];

    constructor(
                private rd: Renderer2,                                        
                private transition: Transition,
                private $state: StateService) {
        this.$stateParams = transition.params();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.Items = getShiftItems();      
    }

    getShiftItems() {
    //calling the service here to load the data in this.Items     

    }


    updateItems() {
     //calling the service here to update this.Items

     }

}
```

```html
 <form novalidate #shiftForm="ngForm" (submit)="updateItems()">
    <table>
    <thead>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>time</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor=let item of Items>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="shiftName" name="shiftName"
                [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftName" #shiftName="ngModel" required>
                <div *ngIf="shiftName.invalid && (shiftName.dirty || shiftName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                   <div *ngIf="shiftName.errors.required">REQUIRED</div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </td>
          <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="shiftTime" name="shiftTime"
                [(ngModel)]="item.ShiftTime" #shiftTime="ngModel" required>
                <div *ngIf="shiftTime.invalid && (shiftTime.dirty || shiftTime.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                   <div *ngIf="shiftTime.errors.required">REQUIRED</div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="shiftForm.invalid"> APPLY </button>
</form>
```